# Calculate sum of series $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-{(\frac{i}{n}})^2}$

Tags: calculus

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}$$

I do not even know where to begin...

Comment: What about Riemann sums ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [right Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_Riemann_sum). Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-\Bigl(\frac in\Bigr)^2}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx.
$$
We have that
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\Bigl[\frac12\Bigl(x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sin^{-1}x\Bigr)\Bigr]_0^1=\frac\pi4.
$$
This is only the limit of the sequence, but for large values of $n$ this is a relatively good approximation. For example, when $n=100$, the sum is approximately equal to $0.7801$ and $\pi/4\approx0.7854
$.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for this limit (though I think it's the only interest of this sum).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Start by rewriting it as

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sqrt{n^2 - i^2}$$

And then try to manipulate it a bit.

For example: $n^2 - i^2 = (n+i)(n-i)$

Comment: I don't see what you intend to do after your example...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a riemann sum for  $f (x)=\sqrt  {1-x^2} $ on $[0,1] $... 
Thus we should be able to find the  limit as $n\to \infty  $ using calculus. ..

> So, we get  $\int_0^1\sqrt  {1-x^2}dx $.
>   To solve this integral,  substitute $x=\sin\theta  $.  Get $$\int_0^{\frac \pi2}\sqrt {1-\sin^2\theta }\cos\theta d\theta =\int_0^\frac \pi2\cos^2\theta d\theta =\frac 12\int_0^\frac \pi2 (\cos 2\theta +1)d\theta =\frac12[\frac {\sin2\theta}2+\theta   ]_0^\frac \pi2=\frac \pi4$$.